# Changing the value of jLabel in jDialog after loading it

Tags: java, multithreading, jlabel, jdialog

I've a `JDialog` with a `JLabel`. I want to change the value of label every 10 seconds.
How can I redraw/repaint the `JDialog` with updated value in `JLabel`.

Comment: If so try like setVisible(false), set the value then setVisible(true)... Give it a try...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [Swing Timer](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to schedule the updates to the label. Then all you do is

```
label.setText(...);
```

and the label will be repainted automatically. There is no need to invoke `repaint()`.

You problem may be that you are trying to start the `Timer` after you display a modal `JDialog`. In this case the code does not execute until the dialog is closed. So you need to make sure you start the `Timer` before using `dialog.setVisible(true)`.

If you need more help then post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) showing the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Timer](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) and [TimerTask](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) to schedule for every 10 seconds, in which you've to furnish the `JLabel`'s `Text` value. After that you've to refresh the current window with `repaint()` method. Now you'll get the `JLabel`'s `Text` value updated...

Comment: I have already coded to call the repaint method. But its not getting the call after setVisible property is set to true.

Comment: If so try like setVisible(false), set the value then setVisible(true)... Give it a try...

Comment: -1, you should NOT be using a util.Timer and util.TimerTask to schedule updates to a Swing component. All Swing components should be updated on the EDT.